# Save draft of Facebook comment for later editing and posting

Tags: facebook

Sometimes I want to start authoring a lengthy comment or comment reply, take a break, then get back to it later.

Seems to me "comment draft" is an appropriate description of what I'm looking for, but nothing seems to come up.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: A Chrome addon called ['comment save'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/comment-save/ndmcbhmmonjkclhmeidccodfhlifmmco) seems relevant, though not exactly built for the purpose I need.